# How to stop an audio from playing based on condition in Python?

Tags: python, multithreading, audio, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I am playing an audio, and simultaneously taking an input from keyboard. I have used threading to achieve this. I created a new thread to run the audio, and listening to the input from main thread. But I want to stop the audio from playing, based on a certain input from keyboard.

Since I can't "kill" a thread from another thread, and I can't make the audio thread listen to the main thread unless it has stopped playing the audio, how do I achieve this?

EDIT:
I have this code written:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import os

p = Process(target=os.system, args=("aplay path/to/audio/file",))
p.start()                                                                                                                 
print("started")                                                             
while p.is_alive():
    print("inside loop")
    inp = input("give input")
    if inp is not None:
        p.terminate()
        print(p.is_alive())     # Returns True for the first time, False for the second time
        print("terminated")
```

This is the output:

```
started
inside loop
give input2
True
terminated
inside loop
give input4
False
terminated
```

Why is this happening? Also, even after the second loop iteration, the process terminates (p.is_alive() returns false) but the audio keeps playing. The audio doesn't stop.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this problem is to the have a common variable/flag between both the threads. The variable will signal the audio playing thread to end or wait for it to be changed.

Here is an example of the same.

In this case the thread will exit on getting the signal.

```
import time
import winsound
import threading

class Player():
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        # Shared Variable.
        self.status = {}
        self.play = True
        self.thread_kill = False
    def start_sound(self):
        while True and not self.thread_kill:
            # Do somthing only if flag is true
            if self.play == True:
                #Code to do continue doing what you want.


    def stop_sound(self):
        # Update the variable to stop the sound
        self.play = False
        # Code to keep track of saving current status

    #Function to run your start_alarm on a different thread
    def start_thread(self):
        #Set Alarm_Status to true so that the thread plays the sound
        self.play = True
        t1 = threading.Thread(target=self.start_sound)
        t1.start()

    def run(self):
        while True:
            user_in = str(raw_input('q: to quit,p: to play,s: to Stop\n'))
            if user_in == "q":
                #Signal the thread to end. Else we ll be stuck in for infinite time.
                self.thread_kill = True
                break
            elif user_in == "p":
                self.start_thread()
            elif user_in == "s":
                self.stop_sound()
            else:
                print("Incorrect Key")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Player().run()
```

Comment: I am not trying to play an audio file in a loop. It's just one long audio file, that I need to interrupt. This line `while self.alarm_status == True: winsound.PlaySound("alarm.wav", winsound.SND_FILENAME)` will work only when the audio file is being played in a loop. It can only check the condition after each full playback. It won't check the condition in between playing the audio file.

Comment: I have edited my answer to pause and continue work in other thread, but for pausing the audio , i guess you either need to decode and stream the file by your own or use such library or have control over the player that you are using (most probably aplay doesn't support pausing).